# What is the type of a function given by a Taylor series.

Tags: taylor-expansion, type-theory

Given a general function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we might say it has type $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

But if it can be written as a Taylor series:

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

Then $f$ is completely determined by the set $\{a_n\}$. which is of the form $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

And so we have two different types which represent the same function $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$.

Should we say that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$? And that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the type of members of a set which contains all functions that can be written as Taylor series? What is the correspondence?

I think this would exclude functions like $1/\sin(x)$ which have an infinite number of poles. (If we let $\infty$ be a member of $\mathbb{R}$.)

This is confusing because it seems to suggest that we can have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ ??

Comment: Although you may uniquely describe the function with an element from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N_0}$ such a description does not describe the mapping between input real values and the corresponding function values which is required to define the function.

Comment: Continuous function are determined by values on rationals. But not all of them are differentiable. Therefore functions with Taylor series are even more rare

Comment: @Peter Yes, but saying a value is from $\mathbb{N}$ does not tell you which value it is either.

Comment: Wthat exactly do you mean by "type"? If $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, then $f \in \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. This is true however $f$ is defined. That a taylor series can be defined using a countable set of numbers has nothing to do with it. The taylor series is not a function of the $a_i$, it is a function of $x$. Constant functions are defined by a single value. As was already mentioned, all continuous functions are determined by only a countable set of values. But all of the functions are in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$. None of them are in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ because their domain is $\Bbb R$, not $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Paul If I knew what I meant I wouldn't be asking the question!

Comment: It is your own terminology. If you have no idea what it means, then nobody else does either. All we can do is explain the actual concepts that you also mention.